# Hide all instances of dynamic button

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery modal being created on the fly, and part of that modal is a series of pre tags. Within the pre tags is a button, for this instance called btnAdd.

Depending, on how many iterations of the loop, i either get one button or several. Now, depending on the users permissions, i need to hide all instances of said button. the following code achieves this for a single instance, but not if there are more generate as part of a loop, with more than one data set

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
       if (!$("#chkAGOG").is(":checked")) {
           $('#btnAdd').hide();
       } else {
           $('#btnAdd').show();
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery selector to achieve this.

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
   if (!$("#chkAGOG").is(":checked")) {
       $("[id$='btnAdd']").hide();
   } else {
       $("[id$='btnAdd']").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` name instead and you can `hide` and `show` all buttons using the `class` name

```
 $('#myModal').on('show', function() {
       if (!$("#chkAGOG").is(":checked")) {
           $('.btnAdd').hide(); //where btnAdd is the class name
       } else {
           $('.btnAdd').show();
       }
   });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wPrqy/)

Comment: adding the class name of 'btn btn-primary' did nothing, infact it stopped the first instance from hidding.

Comment: check the fiddle in my answer